# why the function giving ans 0

Tags: c, while-loop

```c
int get_fact(int N)
{
    int fact=1;
    while(N--)
       {

       fact=fact*N;

       }
    return fact;

}
```

Why it is giving ans zero??

Tried to have the factorial of N.
here while loop used.but somehow 0 is multiplicatd. But why this happened?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could (and should) run your program in a debugger and step through each instruction while watching your variables. What value does `N` have in the last iteration, i.e. when `N==1` and after condition `N--` was evaluated? What will `fact=fact*N;` yield in this last iteration?

Answer (score 1):

A while loop let you do repeated execution of code until the Boolean value becomes false(when the condition becomes 0).
This line

```
while (N--)
```

will continue executing until the value of N equals 0, at which point the condition becomes false. Any number multiplied by 0 results in 0.
There's your answer.

Change that to:

```
int get_fact(int N)
{
    int fact = 1;
    while(N)
    {
       fact = fact * N;
       N--;
    }
    return fact;

}
```

On the difference between prefix and postfix ++ in C, see also;
[https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/readings/autoincrement.990118.html](https://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/readings/autoincrement.990118.html)